# Should I be able to test AuthorizeAttribute and RequireHttpsAttribute with localhost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have been building with MVC 5 for about a month now. Before I get to deep in my project I want to make sure I get security done and also I build a secure web site. I have created 5 pages that should be available to everyone and I am about to implement AspNet.Idenity. But first I wanted to test that the following works as expected. Basically I was expecting all pages to fail for security reasons except the home page. Based on my research if I add:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
    filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
}
```

every page should require HTTPS and a logged in user. 
I only decorated the Home, index controller with [AllowAnonymous] just so I can land on one page when I start the project. I was expecting every other page to fail, or error or redirect to login (not sure how since this is not HTTPS yet).

But every page works with no problems. Should I be able to test this using localhost, or I really need an server environment with IIS? I understand that that is a possibility for HTTP, but I would think that AuthorizeAtribute should be easily tested and fail. What am I not doing right?

Comment: have you added the [authorize] attribute to the controllers and actions you want to have only for authorized users? also, https can be tested easily on local iis (if you modify your hosts file and generate a key) instead of iis express.

Comment: If I understand this correctly we set the AuthorizeAttribute globally in global.asax and then we do whitelisting by explicitly decorating the method with the AllowAnonymous attribute  the methods you want to opt out of authorization is considered a best practice in securing your action methods. So I am expecting this to be set globally with out adding anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

But [AuthorizeAttribute](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) depends on an implementation of `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` in order to function. So it does not work without first implementing your choice of authentication model.

And [RequireHttpsAttribute](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/RequireHttpsAttribute.cs) requires you to have an SSL certificate installed on the local IIS in order to function correctly.

But once the dependencies added to make the attributes function, they will function locally the same as they do on a web server.